# Append css styles after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically add html content to a page whenever the user clicks in different buttons. I'm using an ajax call to get json data from the backend.

The problem is that the data is correctly added but I can't see it on the page (I see it only looking at the html with the Developer Tools). It probably has to do with the css styles not applying after the ajax call but I couldn't solve it.

I tried using several jquery methods like: bind, delegate, on without luck.

```
$('.rubro').on('click', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault;
        var subcat = $(this).attr('id');
        url = '/subcat/' + subcat;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            success: function(data) {   
                var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
                var categories = parsedData['cats'];
                var categories_elements = '';
                var batch_size = 5;
                while (categories.length) {
                    categories_elements += '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">'
                    $.each(categories.splice(0, batch_size), function(i, cat){
                            categories_elements += '<div class="fh5co-counter to-animate">' +
                            '<i class="fh5co-counter-icon icon-briefcase to-animate-2"></i>' +
                            '<span class="fh5co-counter-label">' + cat['stringified_path'] +  ' -> ' + cat['name'] + '</span>' + 
                            '</div>' + 
                            '</div>'
                    });
                 }
                 $('#pop_cats').append(categories_elements);
```

These are the buttons:

```
<button id="1055" class="btn btn-success rubro">Celulares</button>
<button id="1648" class="btn btn-success rubro">Computación</button>
```

Comment: instead of `$('#pop_cats').append(categories_elements);` can u please try `$('#pop_cats').append($(categories_elements));`. that is create jQuery object first before appending it to document.

Comment: are you getting any error ? P.S your are missing `;` at the end of '</div>' closing `categories_elements`

Comment: `It probably has to do with the css styles not applying after the ajax call` No CSS style as defined in stylesheet is applied to any dynamic element. Are you instead using any plugin which need to be initialized on these dynamic elements? Anyway, for sure a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help

Comment: @M.Tanzil This is optional here

Comment: @vijayP I tried that but didn't solve the problem